# Dell 3542 display

Tags: dell-inspiron, laptop-repair, laptop-display

Horizontal pink and blue flickering lines appearing on Dell 3542 laptop display. They don't appear as I start my laptop. They take a few minutes to appear after startup. Any guess what could be wrong ?

Comment: Almost impossible to diagnose in text. Highest probabilities; failing screen, connector cable or GPU; any of these could get worse as the machine warms through. Take it to a professional.

Comment: Most dell laptops have full hardware diagnostics you can run in the Bios, run the full (e)PSA tests.>>>>https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-us/sln115162/resolve-hardware-issues-with-built-in-and-online-diagnostics-supportassist-epsa-epsa-or-psa-error-codes?lang=en#How